# Weird ArgumentException using IsolatedStorageFile and BitmapImage

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, exception, windows-phone-8

I'm using the following code to read some cached images from an IsolatedStorageFile:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storageFile.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
        result.SetSource(stream);
        return result;
    }
}
```

From time to time I get the following exception:

[image]

The detail has the following text:

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection

Any ideas? I don't know if this matters but this code is accessed in a heavy multithreaded environment (I mean that there are a lot of threads calling these lines).

I know this is a first chance exception but anyway I don't get the reason.

Comment: You sure the image is stored correctly, ie. not corrupted?

Comment: That would cause this kind of exception? I really don't know if the image is corrupted or not.

Comment: I have no idea actually, it was just a shot in the dark from me.

Comment: is the exception handled by the framework or does it actually not work?

Comment: What does the stack trace show you? It probably goes into the .Net code itself. But it might be useful to see what throws the exception from within `BitmapImage.SetSource(IsolatedStorageFileStream)`

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: the stack trace just shows one method: Filestream.Read(byte[], int, int) ... weird.

Comment: @Oren: the image shows empty but no unhandled exception so the exception is handled but the call is not working ...

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same error with very similar code. in my experience it only happens on a corrupt photo file.  the photos are all generated by the CameraCaptureTask and i have never been able to reproduce the error, but it happens in the wild.

the error message is a bit misleading.

i'm explicitly calling Close+Dispose on the filestream but that is equivalent to the "using" declarations, ignacio is correct in his reply above.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second using statement for stream object which will fix the issue.

Comment: IsolatedStorageFileStream implements IDisposable so probably not using the 'using' keyword will introduce memory leaks.